# Why is SUM query is extremely slow even for small numbers of records?

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table `amounts` that has about 30mil records in it. I want to be able to sum the values of certain  subsets of those amounts. However mysql takes a extremely long time to do this.

For example if I run the query:

```
select amount from amounts limit 100;
```

I get the result in 0.0096s, however if I run:

```
select sum(amount) from amounts limit 100;
```

It takes 9.624s, if I run EXPLAIN I get the following:

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, amounts, , ALL, , , , , 28022610, 100.00,
```

I'm struggling to understand why it would take that long to sum 100 decimals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your second query apart:

```sql
select sum(amount) from amounts limit 100;
```

Two things are happening here.  First, you are asking MySQL to sum the `amount` column over the *entire* table.  This necessitates touching every record in the table, and given that there is no `WHERE` filter, MySQL would likely not use any index, but would opt for a full table scan.  Second, you have a `LIMIT` clause.  But, since `SUM(amount)` just returns a single record/result, the `LIMIT` clause is superfluous and won't really do anything.

In your first query, you are running `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.  This means that MySQL can, in theory, just pick the first 100 records it comes across and return them.  This, in turn, might mean that it doesn't even have to scan the entire table, it can just do something like read the first few pages, whichever come first.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wanted

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
    FROM ( SELECT amount
               FROM amounts
               ORDER BY ...  -- see Tim's Answer
               LIMIT 100
         ) AS x;
```

That, unlike your `sum`, will add up only 100 items.  First the "derived table" gathers 100 values; then the outer table does the summing.